# When clicking on 'i' icon text comes but it disappears the 'i' icon button

Tags: react-native

I have this code  . When I Click in 'i' icon it tooltip text 'This is tooltip!' comes but icon button disappears but  if I move that icon button to left , then it doesn't disappears . I want icon button on the right side only.
please help me on this.

```
<View style={{
  height: 15,
  marginTop: 10,
  marginBottom: 7
}}>
  <Tooltip
    title={
      <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 8,
      }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>This is a tooltip!</Text>
      </View>
    }
    enterTouchDelay={0}
    leaveTouchDelay={2500}
    visible={visible}
  >
    <IconButton
      icon="information"
      disabled={false}
      size={20}
      onPress={handleIconPress}
      style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 8 }}
    />
  </Tooltip>
</View>
```

I am expecting a when Click on icon it should not disappears.